# Next-Auth SIGNIN_OAUTH_ERROR on google provider

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I implemented login with next-auth. The signin and signout for google provider work on the index page but when I visit to another page the signing attempt gives an error like in below:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object
```

I use signIn and signOut method like in the below:

```
await signIn(provider.id, {callbackUrl: "/"})
await signOut({callbackUrl: "/"})
```

Here is how I set google provider in the nextauth setings:

```
GoogleProvider({
  clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  authorization: {
    params: {
      prompt: 'consent',
      access_type: 'offline',
      response_type: 'code',
    },
  },
}),
```

I also set NEXTAUTH_SECRET parameter in the nextauth settings

```
secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance